# apps script css change placeholder color by class NOT working

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-sites

I just want to change the text color of an input placeholder.  I'm building this page in the Google Apps for Work "Sites" app. This is code from a test I'm using.  I've tried like a zillion combinations without success.  Heeeelp!

my "index" page:

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Styles').getContent(); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="required" id="yo" placeholder="test me" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My "Styles" html:

```
<!-- This CSS package applies Google styling; it should always be included. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<style>
<!--Set default style for all placeholder text-->
input.required:-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #FABBBB;
}

input.required:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #FABBBB;
}

input.required::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #FABBBB;
}

input.required:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: #FABBBB;
}

</style>
```

Here's my "doGet" code:

```
/**
 * Serves HTML of the application for HTTP GET requests.
 * If folderId is provided as a URL parameter, the web app will list
 * the contents of that folder (if permissions allow). Otherwise
 * the web app will list the contents of the root folder.
 *
 * @param {Object} e event parameter that can contain information
 *     about any URL parameters provided.
 */
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Retrieve and process any URL parameters, as necessary.
  if (e.parameter.folderId) {
    template.folderId = e.parameter.folderId;
  } else {
    template.folderId = 'root';
  }

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Comment: How does your `doGet` look like?

Comment: If you use `<?!= ?>` code, you also need to `createTemplateFromFile()` and then `evaluate()` it. If that's OK, Sam's solution should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
input.required::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #FABBBB;
}
```

Note, two colons for webkit.  This page has them listed for the other browsers - have not tested though.

Comment: I added the two colons and it didn't help.